# Change loop inside a loop with Matlab

Tags: matlab, performance, loops, for-loop

I looked in the Matlab handbook and various posts but nothing seems to fit. You find the problematic code below.

My code runs fine, however, I am not sure about the loops for Year and PartOfYear. I want my code to run for Year = 2008:2016 and for PartOfYear = 1:2, however, when Year = 2017, it should only run for PartOfYear = 1. I.e., there is NO PartOfYear = 2 when Year = 2017.
Is there a more efficient (or even correct, as mine is probably incorrect) way of doing this?
At the moment I just tried to run PartOfYear = 1 again whenever it gets to Year = 2017, PartOfYear = 2, and thereby just do this part of the code twice, but I believe it is incorrect as well as inefficient, as the results seem to be off.

Thank you!

```
for index = 1:20

StartYearData = 2008;
EndYearData = 2017;

for Year = StartYearData:EndYearData
    for PartOfYear = 1:2

        if PartOfYear == 1
            StartDayData = 1;
            StartMonthData = 1;
            EndDayData = 30;
            EndMonthData = 6;

        elseif PartOfYear == 2
            StartDayData = 1;
            StartMonthData = 7;
            EndDayData = 31;
            EndMonthData = 12;

            % THIS IS THE WAY I USE TO TRY AND FIX MY PROBLEM
            % BUT I BELIEVE IT IS WRONG OR AT LEAST INEFFICIENT:
            if Year == 2017
                PartOfYear = 1; StartDayData = 1; StartMonthData = 1;
                EndDayData = 30; EndMonthData = 6;
            end
        end 

% DO A LOT OF THINGS

end
```

Comment: If I understand correctly is the first part of year (month 1-6) always 30 days long for each month? and months 7-12 are 31 days? Is this what you want it to do?

Comment: Also regarding the loops have you tried using 'switch' (see https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/switch.html) ? That might be a slightly better way. so you can have something alike for switch Year, case 2017

Comment: Looks like you just want to use `if Year > 2016`? It's unclear what you're asking, please show us your expected outputs for each year, or what you're actually trying to *do*.

Comment: I edited my question! (even though it was already quite clear: I wanted to "make sure that my code runs from 2008 to 2016 for PartOfYear = 1:2 and in 2017 only for PartOfYear = 1") I've never worked with switch - are you sure it's a good way? And is my way just inefficient or could the results be wrong because "loop index is changed inside a for loop"?

Comment: @Wolfie yes, that's a possibility, but how can I nest the for-loop with the if-statement? I tried different ways and couldn't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change a loop variable inside the loop. It looks like you're just getting confused with the ordering of the loops and the `if` statement.

There are lots of ways to achieve what you've asked. This code should do what you want, and only use `PartOfYear = 1` (not `=1:2`) when `Year = 2017`:

```
for index = 1:20    
    StartYearData = 2008;
    EndYearData = 2017;    
    for Year = StartYearData:EndYearData 
        % If the year is 2017, we only want to use PartOfYear=1, otherwise 1:2
        if Year == 2017
            parts = 1;
        else
            parts = 1:2;
        end
        % Now we can loop over the 'parts', which is either 1 or 1:2
        for PartOfYear = parts 
            StartDayData = 1;   % This is the same regardless of PartOfYear value 
            if PartOfYear == 1
                StartMonthData = 1;
                EndDayData = 30;
                EndMonthData = 6;    
            elseif PartOfYear == 2
                StartMonthData = 7;
                EndDayData = 31;
                EndMonthData = 12;    
            end     
            % Stuff...
        end
    end
end
```